# Let A and B be two random variables, both independent from another random variable C. Is A*B also independent from C?

Tags: probability, random-variable, independence

Let A and B be two random variables both independent from another random variable C. If A is independent from B, is A*B also independent from C? And if A and B are no independent from each other?

Comment: Because $(A,B)\to AB$ is a function of the random variable $(A,B),$ this question is a special case of the duplicate question.

Comment: I can provide a counter-example where the independence is pairwise.  Suppose $(A,B,C,AB)$ can take any of the values $(0,0,0,0)$, $(0,1,1,0)$, $(1,0,1,0)$, $(1,1,0,1)$ each with probability $\frac14$.  Then you have pairwise independence of $A$ and $C$, of $B$ and $C$, and of $A$ and $B$.  But $AB$ and $C$ are not independent as $P(AB=1\mid C=0)=\frac12\not= 0=P(AB=1 \mid C=1)$

Comment: @Henry That is a sufficiently interesting and clarifying example (pointing to the possibility of another interpretation of the question) to warrant re-opening this question: thank you.

Answer (score 17):

If all you have is pairwise independence then there is a counterexample.  Suppose the following four cases each have probability $\frac14$:

```
A B C  AB

0 0 0  0 

0 1 1  0 

1 0 1  0 

1 1 0  1
```

Then $A$ is independent of $C$ and $B$ is independent of $C$, and $A$ is independent   of $B$.

But $AB$ and $C$ are not independent as $\mathbb P(AB=1\mid C=0)=\frac12\not= 0=\mathbb P(AB=1 \mid C=1)$

In this example $A$, $B$ and $C$ are *pairwise* independent as suggested by the question, but are not *mutually* independent.  If they had been mutually independent then it would also follow that $AB$ would be independent of $C$. A slightly weaker condition is that if $A$ and $B$ were *jointly* independent of $C$ then it would follow that $AB$ would be independent of $C$ even if $A$ and $B$ were not independent of each other.

Comment: Remark: $C = A \operatorname{XOR} B$, and $AB = A \operatorname{AND} B$; this might give some insight on the structure of the counterexample.

Comment: Another counterexample: take $A$ and $C$ to be independent coin-flips valued in $\{-1,1\}$, and then take $B = A/C$.  It’s not hard to check that $B$ is independent of $C$, and it’s immediately clear that $AB$ is not independent of $C$.

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding this answer and comments.  The question specifies that A, B, and C are all random variables independent of each other.  In the answer aren't you missing 4 rows: 001, 010, 100, and 111 for ABC?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat In my example, can you see that $A$ and $C$ are independent? Can you see that $B$ and $C$ are independent? Can you see that $A$ and $B$ are independent?

Comment: I think I see what you mean in that There is an equal likelihood of C being 0 or 1 if A is 0 or A is one and if B is or or B is 1.   But then isn't C not an '*random variable*' because it's value is totally dependent on the values of A and B?  There is a 0 percent chance of C being 0 in the case of A and B being 0?

Comment: @JasonGoemaat: $C$ has a probability of $\frac12$ of being $1$ and probability $\frac12$ of being $0$ so $C$ is a Bernouilli random variable with parameter $p=\frac12$; so too are $A$ and $B$, while $AB$ is a Bernouilli random variable with parameter $p=\frac14$